# Can I define an in-cycle variable in T-SQL SELECT (like LET in LINQ)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I can write something like this with LINQ:

```
var selection = from person in personList
                let initials = person.FirstName[0] + person.LastName[0]
                select initials;
```

Can I do something similar with SQL, like maybe:

```
SELECT @Initials
FROM [Person]
SET @Initials = SUBSTRING (Person.FirstName, 1, 1) + SUBSTRING (Person.LastName, 1, 1)
```

Probably not but maybe there is a trick?

I need to have a precalculated variable for further use in a complex WHERE clause to avoid extreme complexity and code repetition.

Comment: Don't use 't-sql' for a tag - use 'tsql' instead. Please pay attention the suggest prompts when tagging your question - any tag with a number < 10 after the name should probably be avoided.

Comment: Why? "T-SQL" is typically used but not TSQL.

Comment: @Mastermind, unfortunately more people historically used tsql, and so we re-tag to that for consistency.

Comment: Because there are 1021 questions on stackoverflow tagged as 'tsql' and NO other questions tagged 't-sql'.  Which tag do you think is preferred here?  Just pay attention to the prompts when adding your tags.

Comment: Or, alternatively, if you really want to go re-tag over 1000 questions, be my guest.

Comment: T-SQL is better IMHO; however, since there are 1021 questions tagged as TSQL and only 3 as T-SQL we should stick with TSQL

Comment: @Mastermind: it's pain in the but to search for "t-sql" than "tsql".

Comment: did you ever get this to work?

Comment: Which one exactly? The thing with LINQ is a known option, with SQL sample it was an imaginary syntax to convey my idea.

Answer (score 15):

A clean way of doing this without adding a temporary table, looping, etc. would be with a Common Table Expression (CTE). Example:

```
;WITH PersonsWithInitials AS
(
    SELECT
        SUBSTRING (COALESCE(Person.FirstName,''), 1, 1)
        + SUBSTRING (COALESCE(Person.LastName,''), 1, 1) AS Initials,            
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        City
    FROM
        [Person]
)
SELECT
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    City,
    Initials
FROM
    PersonsWithInitials
WHERE
    /* Complex WHERE clause goes here and it can reference Initials as if it were a field */
```

In place of empty '' above, you could use a period or something else to stand in for null name fields.

This should all be executed in a single SQL call from .NET -- the CTE is not saved in the database like a view, stored procedure, temp table, etc.

Comment: would need to test for NULL cases

Comment: the OP says "I need to have a precalculated variable for further use in a complex WHERE clause".  from their question, it looks like they want to store the results in a variable, not just return a one time result set.  If not, then this is a good answer, otherwise they need to check out my answer...

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're just trying to get the initials into a variable for later.  Try it this way...

```
DECLARE @Initials varchar(2)

SELECT @Initials = SUBSTRING (Person.FirstName, 1, 1) + SUBSTRING (Person.LastName, 1, 1)
FROM   [Person]
WHERE  ....
```

If you're trying to use that as a set and not a single value, you should look at doing a subquery or CTE with your other complex query.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Initials
    = SUBSTRING (Person.FirstName, 1, 1)
      + SUBSTRING (Person.LastName, 1, 1)
FROM [Person]
```

or

```
SELECT SUBSTRING (Person.FirstName, 1, 1) 
       + SUBSTRING (Person.LastName, 1, 1)
            AS Initials
FROM [Person]
```

If you need to use it later, a clearly readable way is to use a common table exprssion (which can be stacked, instead of nested):

```
WITH Person2 AS (
    SELECT SUBSTRING (Person.FirstName, 1, 1) 
           + SUBSTRING (Person.LastName, 1, 1)
                AS Initials
    FROM [Person]
)
SELECT Initials, COUNT(*) AS Record_Count
FROM Person2
GROUP BY Initials
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish LET type functionality using `CROSS APPLY`.

```sql
SELECT Calculations.Initials
FROM [Person]
CROSS APPLY(SELECT SUBSTRING (Person.FirstName, 1, 1) + SUBSTRING (Person.LastName, 1, 1) as Initials) as Calculations
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to keep a set of initials to use multiple times, or as part of a larger query, do the following:

```
declare @TableVariable  table (Initials varchar(200)

INSERT INTO @TableVariable  
        (Initials)
    SELECT
        ISNULL(SUBSTRING(Person.FirstName,1,1),'')+ISNULL(SUBSTRING(Person.LastName,1,1),'')
    FROM Person

SELECT * FROM @TableVariable

SELECT * FROM @TableVariable
```

if you are doing many rows #temp tables are faster.  Also, it would probably be faster to just make this a derived table in a bigger query than using a temp table.

Comment: A table variable may drastically hamper performance if the OP's query filters on more than just initials. In most cases, a CTE will be better, since it uses the underlying table's indexes (a table variable does not).

Comment: @richardtallent, read the question & my answer! I said "if you want to keep a set of initials to use multiple times". also from the OP's question he is trying to put the results into a variable.  You can't do that with a CTE. I was only suggesting a different type of solution!